# Why can't I kill the firefox processes?

Tags: process

My firefox didn't respond when I wanted to download a picture from photos.google.com. Then I clicked "x" to close its window which has multiple tabs open.

Then I wanted to start firefox, but it didn't respond. I find there are several related processes in the output of `ps aux | grep -i firefox`, but `kill` their pid doesn't work. How can I remove the firefox-related processes, so that i  can restart firefox?

The statuses of the firefox-related processes are `D`, `Dl`, and `S+`. What do they mean respectively?

My os is Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Per a related question [over at Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360252/what-do-the-stat-column-values-in-ps-mean)

`D` means the process is in uninterruptible sleep, which is why you can't kill it with an interrupt

`S` is for an interruptible sleep

`+` is the foreground process

`l` means it's multithreaded

Answer (score 0):

> killall -9 firefox firefox-bin

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work.