# Firefox freezes, can't be killed, and Debian 11 XFCE can't be shut down

Tags: debian, xfce, firefox, kill, shutdown

**Problem:** (has been happening every day, at least once, but commonly many times)

1. I have a `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)` system where `Firefox 102.9.0esr (64-bit)` has been randomly freezing and needing to be closed. It gives me "This window might be busy and is not responding. Do you want to terminate the application?";
2. It can be closed through the dialog, or the right button of the mouse, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, but I can't open it again because the processes keep running, even though there is no Firefox on the screen, and I get some error like 'there is another instance already running';
3. I open `xfce-taskmanager`, but trying to `kill` `[firefox-esr]` does no result;
4. I then start killing each process under `[firefox-esr]` on the processes tree, but some of them, just like `[firefox-esr]`, simply are immortal;
5. At this point, I see that the battle is lost, and decide to restart the system. I close everything else and use the graphical system menu to shutdown or reboot. It does nothing;
6. I cut the PC energy supply and replug it again, doing the worst kind of reboot possible, but the only one that I'm able to.

This is not what I expect from a GNU/Linux system: to behave like a Microsoft/Windows system.

**Questions:** (not all of them need to be answered, I just need something that works on my context)

1. why is Firefox misbehaving, and how to properly educate it?
2. which silver bullet I have to kill walking-dead Firefoxes?
3. which guidance can I offer to the Deb/Ian couple in order to make them stop spoiling little Firefoxy? It should not have so much power, to block a shutdown/reboot every time by just doing the same tantrum again and again!

**What has been tried so far:**

1. I checked that there is always plenty of RAM available out of my 8GB, so [it's not like Firefox eating up all memory available](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668510/debian-11-freezes-with-firefox);
2. I already ran `memtest86+` and there was `1 Pass` with `0 Errors`, so no RAM fault here;
3. I used `ps aux | grep -i firefox` to list all processes, [like another user did more than 6 years ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303778/why-cant-i-kill-the-firefox-processes), and kill them with `kill 1333 1387 1431 1471 1530 2039 2211 2259 2284 2310 2317 2365`. This resulted, when running `ps aux | grep -i firefox`, on this output: `laborat+    1333 20.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   11:11   7:45 [firefox-esr] <defunct>`.
4. Still, the GUI `xfce-taskmanager` listed more processes open, not listed by `ps aux | grep -i firefox`, and `kill 1333 2039 1530 1471 1431 2259 2211 2284 2317 2310 1387` did no result at all on them.

These are the immortal PIDs that `xfce-taskmanager` lists, but `kill` cannot `kill`:
[image: Immortal PIDs]

5. `tail /var/log/kern.log` points out `nouveau` errors:

```
Mar 23 23:01:33 debian2022 kernel: [    9.759463] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
Mar 23 23:01:33 debian2022 kernel: [    9.759486] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
Mar 23 23:01:34 debian2022 kernel: [   11.711357] usblp0: removed
Mar 23 23:01:34 debian2022 kernel: [   11.712283] usblp 1-1:1.1: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 2 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x8D11
Mar 23 23:01:46 debian2022 kernel: [   22.779522] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load nouveau/nv98_fuc084 (-2)
Mar 23 23:01:46 debian2022 kernel: [   22.779528] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv98_fuc084 failed with error -2
Mar 23 23:01:46 debian2022 kernel: [   22.779540] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load nouveau/nv98_fuc084d (-2)
Mar 23 23:01:46 debian2022 kernel: [   22.779542] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv98_fuc084d failed with error -2
Mar 23 23:01:46 debian2022 kernel: [   22.779544] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
Mar 23 23:01:46 debian2022 kernel: [   22.779546] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
```

6. `hardinfo` tells me I have `VGA compatible controller       : NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 2] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`.
7. [As suggested elsewhere on UNIX Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/690739/revisions), I tried [following the "Firmware" tutorial on the Nouveau website](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/VideoAcceleration.html), as follows:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/nouveau
$ cd /tmp/nouveau
$ wget https://raw.github.com/envytools/firmware/master/extract_firmware.py
$ wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/325.15/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-325.15.run
$ sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-325.15.run --extract-only
$ python extract_firmware.py
# mkdir /lib/firmware/nouveau
# cp -d nv* vuc-* /lib/firmware/nouveau/
```

But it did result in this other problem:

```
python extract_firmware.py
Skipping gzip blob at 0x5d92e4 (33440 bytes), wrong magic: 0x2
Skipping gzip blob at 0x5da444 (7648 bytes), wrong magic: 0x100c
```

There is just ONE result on the entire web for these two errors: [an IRC channel log](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Ecbrill/dri-log/index.php?channel=nouveau&date=2021-02-18), that does not solves anything.

And I did not notice anything different... What was I supposed to expect after these commands?

Comment: It doesn't have to be Firefox. It could be, for example, your graphics driver or a faulty kernel module, or ... Those things can bring down the whole system. As for `kill`, try killing with `kill -9`, it's not great, but I guess it beats unplugging the system. You can use `top` and see which processes are using the CPU, and memory (press `M`). And, maybe first of all, you really need to check the logs for errors or warnings with something like `tail /var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani "Those things can bring down the whole system." You are correct. Sometimes I can't even change to the TUI to do `shutdown -r now` because the whole system froze, or I'm watching a video and it loops forever the last 3 seconds and I can't do anything else. I'll check the logs tomorrow and update the question if I find something interesting.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Hello! I did `tail /var/log/kern.log` as you requested, and found `nouveau` firmware errors. Is this what we are looking for? (I updated the question including details)

Comment: @EduardoTrápani If I remember correctly, the system froze completely, I cut the energy supply, and restarted the system. So this could be from the booting up again.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I did the following this time: I made a backup of the `/var/log/kern.log`, and started a blank one. When the PC froze and I needed to cut the power supply in order to reboot, the first thing I did was a copy of the log, and then erased it again. It resulted that I have 2 very similar logs now, that differ on the USB devices attached and things like that. But they don't seem much different from each other, nor bring evidence to the problem: log 1 https://pastebin.com/CWzSs1WM and log 2 https://pastebin.com/MQJ2SBWH .

Comment: Sorry, no idea ...

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Thank you for trying.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As for **question 3**, the way to restart the system when the GUI isn't helping is:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to a TUI;
2. login as `root`;
3. do `shutdown -r now`.

It will still be annoying to have Firefox freezing and not being able to start it over without rebooting, but at least you will be able to reboot safely.